# Filter Dataframe with MultiIndex by specific index value

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'm working in forecasting the demand of a product using many scenarios per year. I have a MulitiIndexed dataframe (Simulation, Year, Month) and need to filter by one of them (let's say Simulation).

```
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1,2020,1), (1,2020,2), (2,2020,1), (2,2020,2)], 
                                 names=['Simulation', 'Year', 'Month'])
d = {'Apples': [1,2,3,4], 'Organes': [4,5,6,8], 'Lemons': [9,10,11,12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=idx)
print(df)
```

```
Simulation   Year    Month     Apples  Oranges  Lemons
1            2020    1         1       4        9
1                    2         2       5        10
2            2020    1         3       6        11
2                    2         4       8        12
```

How can I filter by Simulation?

Expected output for filtering by simulation number 1 only

```
Simulation   Year    Month     Apples  Oranges  Lemons
1            2020    1         1       4        9
1                    2         2       5        10
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Javier! I recommend you to read the help page [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It is very important you share a snippet of the code you are using to achieve, check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). More information, more possibilities to have very good answers to solve your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you want to index where `Simulation` is 1, you can use [`index.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html) as:

```
df[df.index.get_level_values(0) == 1]

                        Apples  Oranges  Lemons
Simulation Year Month                         
1          2020 1          10       30      10
                2          25       50       5
           2030 12         30       70       5
```

For multiple values, you can add an [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) at the end to values in a list:

```
df.loc[df.index.get_level_values(0).isin([1, 2])]


                        Apples  Oranges  Lemons
Simulation Year Month                         
1          2020 1          10       30      10
                2          25       50       5
           2030 12         30       70       5
2          2020 1          15       25      10
                2          20       50      15
```

`get_level_values` is basically returning a `Int64Index` containing all indices along the first axis:

```
df.index.get_level_values(0)
# Int64Index([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 50], dtype='int64', name='Simulation')
```

We can then use the result to perform boolean indexing on the dataframe along the axis of interest.

---

Or you can also use [`pd.IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html):

```
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[[1,2], :, :]]

                        Apples  Oranges  Lemons
Simulation Year Month                         
1          2020 1          10       30      10
                2          25       50       5
           2030 12         30       70       5
2          2020 1          15       25      10
                2          20       50      15
```

Comment: Thanks! Very clear and comprehensive.